# What is the format to add an item to an XMLListCollection?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, mxml

I'm trying to create an add row button, and lots of the examples I have seen mention adding an item to the end of the dataProvider. So far, all of these examples have used `ArrayCollection`s, but for my use, `XMLListCollection` works better. What is the format when adding and item to the `XMLListCollection`? Is it the same as an `ArrayCollection`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it the same as an ArrayCollection?

Yes. You can see in the documentations that both [`XMLListCollection`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/collections/XMLListCollection.html) and [`ArrayCollection`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/collections/ArrayCollection.html) extend and get most of their functionality from [`ListCollectionView`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/collections/ListCollectionView.html), which includes the following methods:

- `addAll(addList:IList):void`
- `addAllAt(addList:IList, index:int):void`
- `addItem(item:Object):void`
- `addItemAt(item:Object, index:int):void`